# Raise event only after dependent properties change value

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have this situation where I have several controls that are related to each other. I use two-way binding for the Current/SelectedValue of said controls, so that when a user changes the value, the change is reflected in the property of my viewmodel. The thing is, after the binding triggers the change at the setter of the changed property I need to change the other controls, based on the first, update the UI and then send only one event with the new values of all the affected properties. I was thinking of doing something in the lines of this (kind of something similar to IEditableObject):

```
public string PropA
{
    get{(...)}
    set
    {
        BeginEdit("PropA");
        PropA = value;
        PropB = SomeValueDependentOnA;
        PropC = SomeValueDependentOnA; 
        OnPropertyChanged("PropA");
        EndEdit("PropA");               //this is propA so send the event         
}

 public string PropB
{
    get{(...)}
    set
    {
        BeginEdit("PropB");
        PropB = value;
        PropA = SomeValueDependentOnB;
        PropC = SomeValueDependentOnB; 
        OnPropertyChanged("PropB");
        EndEdit("PropB");         
}

(...)
```

The begin/endedit methods would not do much, just check whether the prop that started the operation is the same that calls the endedit, so further beginedits would be ignored. The EndEdit we would make sure that only in the setter of PropA can we be certain that all the properties changed and we can send the event, kind of a transaction.

Although I think this would work, I think this is kind of too much to be doing on the setter and the begin/endedit seems overkill for this simple thing.

Maybe using 2-way binding is not the best option for this case and I should do the updates from methods in code behind instead of the property setters.

Any sugestions on how to do this other way?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO most 'kosher' approach here is to use `DependecyProperties` having conflict code inside their coerce handlers, like UI components do.

Another way is to apply logic on VM fields, not properties, and then fire `UpdateTarget()` for bindings.

Comment: I'll give it a try with the DependencyProperties. I didn't quite understood the other way you are talking about, could you please be a little more clear (i got the part of the UpdateTarget part but how/where would I apply logic to the fields?). The second sugestion I would have to setup the bindings using the Explicit Mode, right?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way I've seen of doing it is:

```
set 
{
    if (PropA != value)
    {
        PropA = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("PropA");
    }
}
```

That way you only trigger knock on changes when the value changes, and subsequent calls (triggered by dependent values) will not trigger more changes.

Comment: You can update the others either directly inside the `if` or in the PropertyChanged handler.

Comment: I thought of updating inside the PropertyChanged handler but the problem is that it'll be bouncing between property setters and the final operation event will be fired multiple times (that's what I'm trying to avoid).

Comment: If you only trigger the event when the value changes from its old value to a different value this won't be a problem.

Comment: PropA changes -> inside the PropertyChanged handler I change PropB -> I'm again inside the PropertyChanged handler;this time i'll try to update PropA but as you said the value is the same so I won't change it, but then I have to change PropC and the value is different and so on. How would I know where to send the operation event because inside the if for PropA I change PropB but inside the PropB if I change PropC. That's my doubt.

Comment: You could change the dependent values inside the setter as well (but then you should raise property changed on everything that's changed).